# Django getting values from postgres JSON field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jsonfield

I have a simple model like:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

The JSONField `data` is in the following structure:

```json
{
  "name": "Brian",
  "skills": [
     {"id": 4, "name": "First aid"},
     {"id": 5, "name": "Second aid"}
  ]
}
```

I'd like to create a query that gets a list of MyModels filtered by the `id` of the `skill` inside the data.

I've tried a few different avenues here, and can do the work in Python but I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this in Django; I think my SQL isn't good enough to figure it out.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
>>> MyModel.objects.filter(data__skills__contains=[{'id':4}, {'id':5}])
```

more about JSON filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield